# Oculus Quest doesn't allow custom apk (Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculusquest

I need to do a project in Unity for the Oculus Quest 1, but I can't get the apk to work on the Quest. The APK does not show up. I have tried it on 2 different Oculus Quests. The option "Install APK file from folder" does not show up at all. We have 3 people working on it and have tried almost everything. We have a developer account so it can't be that. If anyone might know what the problem is, let me know.

Comment: Are you sure it is not showing when you filter apps on Quest by "unverified"?

Comment: Have you tried using "Build and Run" from Unity?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install it with adb. (make sure you install adb driver.)

[image]

Then on oculus, under `unknown sources`

[image]